# A major scale flat and natural accidental

Tags: theory, scales

Wikipedia states the following for the [A major scale](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_major)

> The key of A major is the only key where a Neapolitan sixth chord on 2 requires both a flat and a natural accidental.

Can anyone explain what the above means and how does that relates to the scale on a guitar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Neapolitan sixth chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neapolitan_chord) is a major triad with its root on the ♭2 of the scale, most commonly played in first inversion. So in A major it is a Bb major triad, which in first inversion is:

`D F Bb`

Since the A major scale contains an F# and a B, in order to get the required F and Bb you need one natural (for the F) and one flat (for the Bb).

Answer (score 0):

```
A Neapolitan sixth chord in A-major (3#) needs a natural (F) and a flat (B) accidental:

Bb  
F♮  
D    

D
```

---

```
Cadence:  

A  Bb_G# A  
E  F♮_E  E  
C# D  D  C#  

A  D  E  A
```